# TypeError: graphql.getDescription is not a function

Tags: graphql, nestjs

I'm trying to integrate graphql in the nest js.
But getting this error.

(node:76308) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: graphql.getDescription is not a function

```
at pushComment (/first-app/dist/merge/src/typedefs-mergers/comments.js:32:21)

at collectComment (/first-app/dist/merge/src/typedefs-mergers/comments.js:8:5)

at /first-app/dist/merge/src/typedefs-mergers/merge-nodes.js:16:17

at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)

at mergeGraphQLNodes (/first-app/dist/merge/src/typedefs-mergers/merge-nodes.js:11:18)

at mergeGraphQLTypes (/first-app/dist/merge/src/typedefs-mergers/merge-typedefs.js:58:25)

at mergeTypeDefs (/first-app/dist/merge/src/typedefs-mergers/merge-typedefs.js:10:22)

at GraphQLTypesLoader.mergeTypesByPaths (/first-app/node_modules/@nestjs/graphql/dist/graphql-types.loader.js:20:42)

at GraphQLModule.onModuleInit (/first-app/node_modules/@nestjs/graphql/dist/graphql.module.js:90:27)

at callModuleInitHook (/first-app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/hooks/on-module-init.hook.js:51:9)
```

(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

Version: "@nestjs/graphql": "^9.0.0"

Please help on this.